# ./util/subst: Command not found

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

Based On:
Linux dev-dsk-sbalamur-1a-e011004b.eu-west-1.amazon.com 5.4.50-36.83.amzn2int.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 9 21:27:17 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
gcc --version | grep gcc
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-9)
```

Hi All,
Iam trying to install the ext2fs library as mentioned in INSTALL file "https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/INSTALL?h=v1.45.6".  But I am
getting the error message pasted below

```
(20-09-20 12:03:09) <0> [~/external/e2fsprogs/build]  
dev-dsk-sbalamur-1a-e011004b % 

(20-09-20 12:07:53) <130> [~/external/e2fsprogs/build]  
dev-dsk-sbalamur-1a-e011004b % ../configure              
Generating configuration file for e2fsprogs version 1.42.9
Release date is December, 2013
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for additional special compiler flags... (none)
Disabling maintainer mode by default
Disabling symlinks for install by default
Disabling relative symlinks for install by default
Disabling symlinks for build by default
Disabling verbose make commands
Disabling compression support by default
Enabling htree directory support by default
Disabling ELF shared libraries by default
Disabling BSD shared libraries by default
Disabling profiling libraries by default
Disabling checker libraries by default
Disabling journal debugging by default
Disabling blkid debugging by default
Enabling testio debugging by default
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
Enabling private uuid library by default
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
Enabling private blkid library by default
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
Disabling quota support by default
Enabling use of backtrace by default
Enabling debugfs support by default
Enabling e2image support by default
Enabling e2resize support by default
Enabling e4defrag support by default
Building fsck wrapper by default
Building e2initrd helper by default
Try using thread local support by default
checking for thread local storage (TLS) class... __thread
Building uuidd by default
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strerror in -lcposix... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for signed... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for long long... yes
checking for long double... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking for wint_t... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking whether printf() supports POSIX/XSI format strings... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2.1 or newer... yes
checking whether integer division by zero raises SIGFPE... yes
checking for unsigned long long... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking whether the inttypes.h PRIxNN macros are broken... no
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for SIZE_MAX... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking argz.h usability... yes
checking argz.h presence... yes
checking for argz.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking nl_types.h usability... yes
checking nl_types.h presence... yes
checking for nl_types.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for fwprintf... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getegid... yes
checking for geteuid... yes
checking for getgid... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for mempcpy... yes
checking for munmap... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for stpcpy... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for tsearch... yes
checking for wcslen... yes
checking for __argz_count... yes
checking for __argz_stringify... yes
checking for __argz_next... yes
checking for __fsetlocking... yes
checking whether _snprintf is declared... no
checking whether _snwprintf is declared... no
checking whether feof_unlocked is declared... yes
checking whether fgets_unlocked is declared... no
checking whether getc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... 
         extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.4, ok
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking whether included gettext is requested... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for GNU make... make
checking for ln... /usr/bin/ln
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for mv... /usr/bin/mv
checking for cp... /usr/bin/cp
checking for rm... /usr/bin/rm
checking for chmod... /usr/bin/chmod
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for ldconfig... /usr/sbin/ldconfig
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for makeinfo... no
checking dirent.h usability... yes
checking dirent.h presence... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for malloc.h... (cached) yes
checking mntent.h usability... yes
checking mntent.h presence... yes
checking for mntent.h... yes
checking paths.h usability... yes
checking paths.h presence... yes
checking for paths.h... yes
checking semaphore.h usability... yes
checking semaphore.h presence... yes
checking for semaphore.h... yes
checking setjmp.h usability... yes
checking setjmp.h presence... yes
checking for setjmp.h... yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking stdarg.h usability... yes
checking stdarg.h presence... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking termios.h usability... yes
checking termios.h presence... yes
checking for termios.h... yes
checking termio.h usability... yes
checking termio.h presence... yes
checking for termio.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking utime.h usability... yes
checking utime.h presence... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking linux/falloc.h usability... yes
checking linux/falloc.h presence... yes
checking for linux/falloc.h... yes
checking linux/fd.h usability... yes
checking linux/fd.h presence... yes
checking for linux/fd.h... yes
checking linux/major.h usability... yes
checking linux/major.h presence... yes
checking for linux/major.h... yes
checking linux/loop.h usability... yes
checking linux/loop.h presence... yes
checking for linux/loop.h... yes
checking net/if_dl.h usability... no
checking net/if_dl.h presence... no
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking sys/disklabel.h usability... no
checking sys/disklabel.h presence... no
checking for sys/disklabel.h... no
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking sys/mkdev.h usability... no
checking sys/mkdev.h presence... no
checking for sys/mkdev.h... no
checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking sys/prctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/prctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/prctl.h... yes
checking sys/queue.h usability... yes
checking sys/queue.h presence... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/sockio.h usability... no
checking sys/sockio.h presence... no
checking for sys/sockio.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/syscall.h usability... yes
checking sys/syscall.h presence... yes
checking for sys/syscall.h... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h usability... yes
checking sys/sysmacros.h presence... yes
checking for sys/sysmacros.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking sys/wait.h usability... yes
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for sys/disk.h... no
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for struct dirent.d_reclen... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking whether llseek is declared... no
checking whether lseek64 is declared... yes
checking size of short... 2
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for __uNN types... using <asm/types.h>
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for intptr_t... yes
checking whether struct stat has a st_flags field... no
checking for struct sockaddr.sa_len... no
checking for __secure_getenv... no
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for blkid_probe_get_topology... no
checking for chflags... no
checking for fallocate... yes
checking for fallocate64... yes
checking for fchown... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for fstat64... yes
checking for ftruncate64... yes
checking for getdtablesize... yes
checking for getmntinfo... no
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for getrlimit... yes
checking for getrusage... yes
checking for jrand48... yes
checking for llseek... yes
checking for lseek64... yes
checking for mallinfo... yes
checking for mbstowcs... yes
checking for memalign... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for msync... yes
checking for nanosleep... yes
checking for open64... yes
checking for pathconf... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for posix_memalign... yes
checking for prctl... yes
checking for secure_getenv... yes
checking for setmntent... yes
checking for setresgid... yes
checking for setresuid... yes
checking for srandom... yes
checking for strcasecmp... (cached) yes
checking for strdup... (cached) yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strptime... yes
checking for strtoull... yes
checking for sync_file_range... yes
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for usleep... yes
checking for utime... yes
checking for valloc... yes
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for optreset... no
checking for sem_init... no
checking for sem_init in -lpthread... yes
checking for unified diff option... -u
On linux-gnu systems, root_prefix defaults to ''
On linux-gnu systems, prefix defaults to /usr
checking whether we can link with -static... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating MCONFIG
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating e2fsprogs.spec
config.status: creating util/Makefile
config.status: creating util/subst.conf
config.status: creating util/gen-tarball
config.status: creating util/install-symlink
config.status: creating lib/et/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/ss/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/e2p/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/ext2fs/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/ext2fs/ext2_types.h
config.status: creating lib/uuid/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/uuid/uuid_types.h
config.status: creating lib/blkid/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/blkid/blkid_types.h
config.status: creating lib/quota/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/ss/ss.pc
config.status: creating lib/uuid/uuid.pc
config.status: creating lib/et/com_err.pc
config.status: creating lib/e2p/e2p.pc
config.status: creating lib/blkid/blkid.pc
config.status: creating lib/ext2fs/ext2fs.pc
config.status: creating misc/Makefile
config.status: creating ext2ed/Makefile
config.status: creating e2fsck/Makefile
config.status: creating debugfs/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/progs/Makefile
config.status: creating resize/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating intl/Makefile
config.status: creating intl/libgnuintl.h
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating lib/config.h
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile

(20-09-20 12:08:13) <0> [~/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build]  
dev-dsk-sbalamur-1a-e011004b % make
make[1]: Entering directory '/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
make[1]: `util/subst.conf' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
make[1]: Entering directory `/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
make[1]: `lib/config.h' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
make[1]: Entering directory `/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
    SUBST lib/dirpaths.h
make[1]: ./util/subst: Command not found
make[1]: *** [lib/dirpaths.h] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/sbalamur/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build'
make: *** [subs] Error 2

(20-09-20 12:08:16) <2> [~/FOS5/external/e2fsprogs/build]  
dev-dsk-sbalamur-1a-e011004b %
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with C++. Note that C and C++ are different languages. Please tag only with the actual language being used.

Comment: @kaylum it has nothing to do with C either. `./util/subst` is not a part of C.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I give the OP the benefit of the doubt. Looks like `subst` is supposed to be built from `subst.c`.

Comment: @kaylum It is indeed supposed to be built, but it doesn't seem to have been built.